# How can i reinitialize the dynamic flexslider on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I want to refresh the flexslider on click event. Actually i add flexslider in bootstrap pop so i want to refresh the slider on click event. Problem is that when i refresh the slider then it does not showing, because slider loss the in line styles of li. I debugged every thing is fine but in-line css are rendering when i refresh the slider.

### For Refresh Slider

```
$(function() {
      $(".sidebar-button").click(function(evt) {
        $(".custom-popup-personalize").load(window.location + " .custom-popup-personalize");
      })
});
```

I will really appreciate if someone give me solution of this problem.[image]

Answer (score -1):

after read plugin doc , something like so maybe help you :

```
$('myslider-inner-div').data('flexslider').setup();
```

OR

trigger your function on tab show event :

```
$('#case-1').on('shown', function () {
    $(window).trigger( 'resize' );
});
```

Comment: Will it refresh my flexslider and how i use it on click event ?